# Getting an empty plot after plotting the solution of a differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am facing problem to plot this

```
 **a = 7.883*10^11
 b = 0.127
 c = 1.6*10^-4
 d = b*10^30
 f[x_, y_] := 
 Sqrt[y] {((y - 1)/y)^2 + 2 ((y - 1)/y)} BesselK[1, x Sqrt[y]]
 g[x_] := -a x^(3/
 2) E^{x} {{b x^(-3/2) E^(-x) BesselK[1, x]/BesselK[2, x]} + 
 c x^(-1) NIntegrate[f[x, y], {y, 1, \[Infinity]}]}
  result[x_] = 
  h[x] /. NDSolve[{h'[x] == g[x] {h[x] - d x^{-3/2} E^{-x}}, 
  h[0.12] == 10^-5}, h[x], {x, 10^-1, 10^2}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 16][[1]];
 LogPlot[result[x], {x, 10^-1, 10^2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10^-1, 10^-2}, {10^-10, 10^0}}]**
```

I am only confused about the boundary condition, is it can be plotted for an best fit boundary, so that I can figure out how the nature of the curve will?

Comment: Braces are used pretty much only to specify lists.  To parse equations, you must use parentheses.  Also there is little point in trying to plot the solution until you have a solution.

Comment: You are getting an empty plot because you aren't getting a solution to differential equation. Even after you fix the syntax errors the resulting system is intractable or nearly so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you can't get your code to work, you need to scale it down until you get it working then build it back up.  Also, need to remove all brackets in equations and replace with parentheses.  If you try plotting the derivative:

```
(g[x] - d x^-(3/2) E^-x)
```

you'll find it's about 10^24 near 0.1.  That's tough to numerically integrate and NDSolve is complaining that the derivative is so large, even an extremely small step size would result in a dramatic change in the estimated value of the function due to the high derivative thus resulting in poor precision.  So how about if we just scale the parameters down just to get it working regardless if it no longer represents the problem:  How about reducing the large values of a and d below.  That works.  Now try raising them back up gradually until it starts failing again, then click on NDSolve help and perhaps read the section on advanced numerical differential equation solving.  I don't know if there is a better method for this type of equation.

```
a = 7.883*10^3;
b = 0.127;
c = 1.6*10^-4;
d = b*10^3;

f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 Sqrt[y] (((y - 1)/y)^2 + 2 ((y - 1)/y)) BesselK[1, x Sqrt[y]]

Clear[g]
g[x_?NumericQ] := -a x^(3/2) E^
   x (b x^(-3/2) E^-x BesselK[1, x]/BesselK[2, x] + 
    c/x NIntegrate[
      Sqrt[y] (((y - 1)/y)^2 + 2 ((y - 1)/y)) BesselK[1, 
        x Sqrt[y]], {y, 1, \[Infinity]}])

mysol = First[
  NDSolve[{h'[x] == g[x] (g[x] - d x^-(3/2) E^-x), h[.12] == 10.^-5}, 
   h, {x, .12, 100.}]]
theF[x_] := Evaluate[Flatten[h[x] /. mysol]];
Plot[theF[x], {x, 0.12, 100}]
```

[image: plot of results]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dominic

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an empty plot because you aren't getting a solution to your differential equation. You should have looked at the results given by `NDSolve` before trying to plot.

That answers you question, but fixing the syntax alone won't get you a plot because your ODE is too nasty for a naive approach; for `NDSolve` a have a chance to solve the ODE will require giving `NDSolve` instructions on what method it should use. I have neither the time nor the expertise to advise you about method.

I did make a stab at correcting the syntax. I am posting my revision to your code here so, should someone else with the proper expertise want to take the matter further, they can use my work as a base for proceeding.

```
a = 7.883*10^11;
b = 0.127;
c = 1.6*10^-4;
d = b*10^30;

f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[y] {((y - 1)/y)^2 + 2 ((y - 1)/y)} BesselK[1, x Sqrt[y]]

Clear[g]
g[x_?NumericQ] :=
  -a x^(3/2) E^x 
    (b x^(-3/2) E^-x BesselK[1, x]/BesselK[2, x] + c/x NIntegrate[f[x, y], {y, 1, ∞}])[[1]]

NDSolveValue[
  {h'[x] == g[x] (h[x] - d x^-(3/2) E^-x), h[.12] == 10.^-5}, 
  h, {x, .1, 100.}]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gold